# Help me with this general mathematics problem

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Find the number of integer values of $-> (144)^{\sin^2(x)}+(144)^{\cos^2(x)}$.

The equation should be read as - ($144$ to the power sin square $x$) $+$($144$ to the power cos square $x$).

Comment: Two hints: $(\sin{x})^2 + (\cos{x})^2 = 1$, $144 = 12^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The expression is $12^{2\sin^2(x)}+12^{2\cos^2(x)}$ now take derivative and set it equal to $0$ to get maxima ,minima.You get $\sin (2x)(144^{\sin^2 (x)}-144^{\cos^2 (x)})=0$ so  $x=0,\frac {\pi}{4} $ thus maxima of function is $145$,minima is $24$. Now let $144^{sin^2 (x)}=y $ then our expression becomes $y+\frac {144}{y} $. This expression is continuous on all values between $24,145$ hence total number of integer solutions are $
122$

Comment: Maybe my hints pointed the wrong way: $144^{(\sin{0.446753})^2} + 144^{(\cos{0.446753})^2} \approx 133$.

Comment: But its approx not exact so your hints are correct.

Comment: But it's continuous so there should be an exact value near there, right?

Comment: There seems to be a minus sign in the question, i.e. $-12^{2\sin^2(x)}+12^{2\cos^2(x)}$.

Comment: I think that should be made clear . Maybe he/she has used it as a dash.

Comment: @Dan Brumleve I have edited the answer. This is the best I can get. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: He uses a minus sign in both lines. That makes me think that it really should be there.

Comment: No there is no minus sign just a dash, sorry for inconvenience 

Answer (score 1):

Let $u = 144^{\sin^2(x)}$

Then $1 \le u \le 144$ and

$f(u) =144^{sin^2(x)} + 144^{cos^2(x)} = u + \dfrac{144}{u}$

This describes a hyperbola with brances in the first and third quadrants. We are interested on in the values in the first quadrant.

Solving $f'(u) = 1 -\dfrac{144}{u^2} = 0$, we get that a global minimum occurs at u = 12, f(u) = 24$.

So the range of $f(u)$ is $[24, 145]$. There are $122$ integers in that range.

Comment: Sorry there was no minus